# Ignoring specific errors in Rollbar based on substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollbar

I have an issue where there are 3 different errors thrown. All 3 have a certain substring in their message which indicates for me that I should ignore it. 
For Example:

```
E_type1::UpdateError 
E_type2::CreationError
E_type3::EditError
```

I would like to add to rollbar's `exception_level_filters` a lambda which ignores all three errors if they include a specific substring, something akin to this:

```
config.exception_level_filters.merge!({
              'ErrorClass:MiscError' => 'ignore',
              'E_type1::UpdateError' => lambda { |e|
                if e.include? 'SUBSTRING'
                  'ignore'
                else
                  e.rollbar_level
                end
              }
            })
```

Except I would like the same lambda to be for all **three** errors.

How can I go about doing this?

Can it be DRY'd up a bit?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there - You can get an answer directly from the Rollbar SDK team by re-posting your question at https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/issues/new.  Rollbar provides support to all customers, regardless of subscription level.